# What is the physical dimension of a reciprocal vector?

Tags: mathematical-physics, dimensional-analysis

The question is of general interest for dimensional analysis. I am trying to formalize the dimensionality of vector spaces.

Consider the usual orthonormal basis of the Euclidean space $e_1, e_2, e_3$.
If we define the reciprocal basis as 
$$e^i = e_i / ( e_i \cdot e_i)$$
does it mean that the physical dimension of $e^i$ is also reciprocal to the dimension of $e_1$?
If $[e_1] =L $, length, is $[e^1]=1/L$?

Comment: Please don't intentionally duplicate questions – it wastes everyone's resources. [Physical dimension of a reciprocal vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559411/physical-dimension-of-a-reciprocal-vector)

Comment: The question was not answered. This is  why I am reposting it.

Comment: Yes. As I said, please don't do that. I've flagged it for moderator attention.

Comment: It also wastes my time to reopen questions. So if you can contribute to an answer please do so.

Comment: The answer's yes, your reasoning is fine.

Comment: Could you post is as an answer for the record?

Answer (score 2):

Working with components, $e^i_j=e_{ij}/\sum_ke_{ik}^2$ is a length over a squared length. Since each component of $e^i$ has dimension $L^{-1}$, so does the vector.